# Xdebug does not work on nginx with php7.3

Tags: php, docker, nginx, xdebug

I have setup a docker container with php 7.3 from `phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest`.
The xdebug is installed properly but it does not debug anything. I cannot make this work so i would need some guidance.

Here is my docker configuration:

> nginx config

```
server {
    server_name lxxxxxv2.local;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    root /app/public;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/lxxxxxxv2.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/lxxxxxv2.local.key;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(index_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass lxxxxv2-php-fpm:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass lxxxxv2-php-fpm:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://symfony3.dev/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/lxxxxv2_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/lxxxxv2_access.log;
}
```

> php output

```
root@9736f96a32ef:/app# php -v
PHP 7.3.12-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:37:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.12, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.12-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/app"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

#add yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg |  apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" |  tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    vim \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    yarn \
    php7.3-mysql \
    php-redis \
    php7.3-xdebug \
    php7.3-gd \
    php7.3-intl \
    php7.3-fpm \
    php7.3-mongodb \
    iputils-ping

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
lxxxxv2-webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: lxxxxxv2-webserver
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - ./log:/log
        - ./Dockerconfig/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ./Dockerconfig/sslcerts/lxxxxxv2.local.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/lxxxxxv2.local.crt
        - ./Dockerconfig/sslcerts/lxxxxxv2.local.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/lxxxxxxv2.local.key
    depends_on:
        - lxxxxv2-php-fpm
        - lxxxxv2-mysql
    links:
        - lxxxxv2-php-fpm
        - lxxxxv2-mysql
    ports:
        - "30080:80"
        - "30443:443"
    expose:
        - "80"
        - "443"
    mem_limit: 300m
    memswap_limit: 300m
    environment:
        - VIRUAL_HOST=lxxxxxv2.local
        - APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER=public/index.php
    networks:
        default:
            aliases:
                - lxxxxxxv2.local


lxxxxv2-php-fpm:
    build: Dockerconfig/php-fpm
    container_name: lxxxxv2-php-fpm
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - ./log:/log
        - ./Dockerconfig/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    ports:
        - "30901:9000"
    expose:
        - "30901"
    extra_hosts:
      - "lxxxxv2.local:0.0.0.0"
    networks:
        - default
    environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.29.0.3 idekey=\"PHPSTORM\" remote_port=9001 remote_connect_back=1 remote_log=\"/var/log/xdebug.log\""
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=lxxxxv2.local"
```

> phpstorm server settings:

[image]

> phpstorm debug settings:

[image]

> php storm DBGp Settings:

[image]

> The output of php -i related to xdebug

```
 php -i | grep -i xdebug
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
    with Xdebug v2.8.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 172.29.0.1 => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => "/var/log/xdebug.log" => no value
xdebug.remote_log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
XDEBUG_CONFIG => remote_host=172.29.0.1 idekey="PHPSTORM" remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
$_SERVER['XDEBUG_CONFIG'] => remote_host=172.29.0.1 idekey="PHPSTORM" remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

Comment: I would reccomend a checklist:
1. check whether the Xdebug has the correct ip

Comment: 2. Use configuration file for Xdebug and use that for the Xdebug configuration.

Once you tried update your answer. That will aid you to come closer to the solution.

In order to find the correct ip run the command `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10` from a shell session inside the docker container.

Comment: Are you sure it's 9001 port? Make sure that no one is listening on that port already (e.g. php-fpm service). Enable logging of xDebug to see if it's hitting target

Comment: Assuming you're running on a Unix environment, can you run and provide the output from `php -i | grep -i xdebug`, please? This will show us all the Xdebug configuration options for Xdebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally make it work with the help of the comments. 
The only thing i had to change is the following line:

**Before**

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.29.0.4 remote_port=9001 idekey=\"PHPSTORM\" remote_log=\"/var/log/xdebug.log\""
```

**After**

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.29.0.1 idekey=\"PHPSTORM\" remote_connect_back=1 remote_log=\"/var/log/xdebug.log\""
```

- remote_host -> from 172.23.0.3 to 172.29.0.1 based on the comment to check `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10`
- remote_port -> removed. the default port is 9000 and this is free based on `netstat -anp | grep CLOSE_WAIT`
- remote_enable = 1 - added. Based on other stackoverflow findings
- remote_autostart = 1 - added. Based on other stackoverflow findings